# How to compare two lists in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, numpy, python-itertools

Suppose I have two lists (or `numpy.array`s):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
```

How can I check if each element of `a` is smaller than corresponding element of `b` at the same index? (I am assuming indices are starting from 0)
i.e.

```
at index 0 value of a = 1 < value of b = 4
at index 1 value of a = 2 < value of b = 5
at index 2 value of a = 3 < value of b = 6
```

If `a` were equal to `[1,2,7]`, then that would be incorrect because at index 2 value of `a` is greater than that of `b`. Also if `a`'s length were any smaller than that of `b`, it should be comparing only the indices of `a` with those of `b`.

For example this pair `a`, `b`

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,4,5]
```

at indices 0 and 1, value of `a` is smaller than `b`, thus this would also pass the check.

P.S.--> I have to use the above conditions inside a `if` statement.
And also, no element of `a` should be equal to that of `b` i.e. strictly lesser. Feel free to use as many as tools as you like. (Although I am using lists here, you can convert the above lists into numpy arrays too.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answering both parts with `zip` and `all`

```
all(i < j for (i, j) in zip(a, b))
```

`zip` will pair the values from the beginning of `a` with values from beginning of `b`; the iteration ends when the shorter iterable has run out. `all` returns `True` if and only if all items in a given are true in boolean context. Also, when any item fails, `False` will be returned early.

Example results:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> all(i < j for (i, j) in zip(a, b))
True
>>> a = [1,2,7]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> all(i < j for (i, j) in zip(a, b))
False
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = [4,5,-10]
>>> all(i < j for (i, j) in zip(a, b))
True
```

Timings with IPython 3.4.2:

```
In [1]: a = [1] * 10000
In [2]: b = [1] * 10000
In [3]: %timeit all(i < j for (i, j) in zip(a, b))
1000 loops, best of 3: 995 µs per loop
In [4]: %timeit all(starmap(lt, zip(a, b)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 487 µs per loop
```

So the starmap is faster in this case. In general 2 things are relatively slow in Python: function calls and global name lookups. The `starmap` of [Retard's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28767765/918959) seems to win here exactly because the tuple yielded from `zip` can be fed as-is as the *args to the `lt` builtin function, whereas my code needs to deconstruct it.

Answer (score 5):

As a variant, fast and short

```
from operator import lt
from itertools import starmap, izip
all(starmap(lt, izip(a, b)))
```

Comment: @Antti Haapala, for the a and b, where a = list(range(10000)) and b = list(range(1, 10001))  On my system your solution gives 809 microseconds and mine is 558

Comment: Indeed yours is the faster one :D because of less tuple creation.

Comment: I'm curious about your testing procedure. Is it possible to provide the code for you test? (You can use http://pythonfiddle.com/)

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't use ```itertools.izip```?

Comment: #wwii, no reason. Thx for idea, will update the answer

Comment: On my system izip is drastically faster

Comment: Hey, we're talking about Python 3. `zip` _is_ `itertools.izip` from Python 2.

Comment: @Matthias
Oh, yeah, tested on python 2, my bad

Answer (score 2):

Since this question has a `numpy` tag, I figured I would provide a `numpy` solution.

You can only use a `<` operator on `arrays` of equal length, therefore if your `arrays` are of different length you need to shorten the longest one.

```
In [26]: import numpy as np

In [27]: a = [1,2,3]

In [28]: b = [4,5,6]

In [29]: np.all(a < b)
Out[29]: True

In [30]: a = [1,2]

In [31]: b = [3,4,5]

In [32]: shortest = min(len(a), len(b))

In [33]: np.all(a[:shortest] < b[:shortest])
Out[33]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative way, and not sure how it performs against the other answers:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
if filter(lambda x: x[0] < x[1], zip(a,b)):
    return True
```

I'm using it within the if-statement since the question indicates, that it's going to be used like that, and there's no need for a bool-conversion there. Otherwise I would've wrapped the filter() inside bool().
Again, this is just to demonstrate an alternative approach, not meaning to be the most efficient one.